# School was fun. vs There was fun at school

Tags: phrase-usage

Could you say please there is any difference? Are both sentences common?

> School was fun.

> There was fun at school.

Are "fun" and "funny" interchangeable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is common, but the second is not.

> 1. School was fun.
> 2. There was fun at school.

The following sentence is not grammatically wrong, but this is not how English native speakers would express the idea.

```
There was happiness at school today.
```

> Are "fun" and "funny" interchangeable here?

No, they are not interchangeable.

Comment: How do you understand "School was fun."? It was interesting to have studies, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1):

"Fun" and "funny" are never interchangeable, here or elsewhere. They are different words, with different meanings.

> School was fun.

This sentence is the natural and common phrasing.

> There was fun at school.

I'm not sure this is actually *wrong*, but it is absolutely weird. There are certainly other nouns I could replace it with to have a grammatically identical sentence that doesn't sound weird (Ex. "There was quiet at school"). It still wouldn't be the most natural way to phrase it in a conversation (I'd say, "School was quiet") but I wouldn't find it odd to read in a book.

Comment: How do you understand "School was fun."? It was interesting to have studies, wasn't it?

Comment: @Sergey Maybe, yes. Or maybe my teachers weren't too strict and my friends and I messed around a lot. Either way, it means I enjoyed it. Funny, on the other hand, means either it made me laugh or there was something strange about it.